# Unity count tags serialization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 3D Unity game. The red cube deletes every element with tag='Enemy' to which it touches during the playtime. The problem occurs when the script tries to count the number of objects with this tag at first. How to fix this problem?

**The error:**

```
 FindGameObjectsWithTag is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead. Called from MonoBehaviour 'Collide'.
See "Script Serialization" page in the Unity Manual for further details.
Collide..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Collide.cs:9)
```

[image: Error]

**The script Collide.cs:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class Collide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text txt;
    public int obji = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        if (collision.collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {

            transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.03F, 0.03F, 0.03F);


            Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
            obji = obji - 1;
            Debug.Log(obji);

            if ((obji) > 0)
            {
                txt.text = (obji).ToString();
            }
            else {
                txt.text = "You win!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message *literally* tells you how to fix it. Put the `obji = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length` into Start/Awake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Piflik said try this

```
public int obji = -1; //this is an example, I always try to initialize my variables.
void Start(){ //or Awake
    obji = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy").Length;
}
```